# looping backward or forward in python list to find a match

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I have a python list in which I will search and find one term. Once I find it, I need to go backward in the list and find the first occurrence with `=` and go forward and find the first occurrence with `;`.

I tried using while loop but it is not working.

```
extract = [1,2,"3=","fd","dfdf","keyword","ssd","sdsd",";","dds"]

indices = [i for i,s in enumerate(extract) if 'keyword' in s] 


for ind in indices:
    ind_while_for = ind
    ind_while_back = ind
    if ('=' in extract[ind]) & (';' in extract[ind]):
        print(extract[ind])   
    if (';' in extract[ind]) & ('=' not in extract[ind]):
        while '=' in extract[ind_while_back-1]:
            ind_while_back -= 1    
        print(' '.join(extract[ind_while_back:ind]))
```

result required : `3= fd dfdf keyword ssd sdsd ;`

Comment: You are definitely confusing `&` and `and`. You need the latter.

Comment: Note that you cannot iterate on the elements within your list which are integers. Your if arguments should be:  if '=' in str(extract[ind]) and ';' in str(extract[ind]):

Comment: Why "loop backwards" when you can simply keep track of the last occurrance of the `=`? Once you find your keyword, you can just keep going until you hit the `;`, and you'll have all the information you need to output the result you want.

Comment: if `extract = ["=keyword;"]`, we should print it?

Comment: if `extract = ['=', 'keyword', ';', '=', 'keyword', 'a;' ]`, we should print two ?

Comment: semicolon is the termination.. and `=` will not come alone..`=` will always have something on left

Answer (score 1):

Find the position of the keyword:

```
kw = extract.index("keyword")
```

Find the element with the largest index that contains an `"="` in the sublist of the original list before the position of the keyword:

```
eq = max(i for i,w in enumerate(extract[:kw]) 
         if isinstance(w,str) and "=" in w)
```

Find the element with the smallest index that contains a `";"` in the sublist from the previous element to the end:

```
semi = min(i for i,w in enumerate(extract[eq:], eq) 
           if isinstance(w,str) and ';' in w)
```

Extract the sublist between the two extremes:

```
extract[eq:semi+1]
#['3=', 'fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd', ';']
```

Comment: `kw = extract.index("keyword")` the keyword maynot have a exact match...may be the search can be for `key` or `eywo` etc

Comment: You must have mentioned that you would accept an approximate match.

Comment: Note that this is going to be very inefficient on long lists. Not an issue for the example one, but it will surely be one if the real dataset is 1000+ items long...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Not _very_ inefficient, as it requires only two passes over the list. But somewhat inefficient, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
l = [1, 2, "3=", "fd", "dfdf", "keyword", "ssd", "sdsd", ";", "dds"]

s = "keyword"

def take(last, iterable):
    l = []
    for x in iterable:
        l.append(x)
        if last in x:
            break
    return l

# get all elements on the right of s
right = take(';', l[l.index(s) + 1:])

# get all elements on the left of s using a reversed sublist
left = take('=', l[l.index(s)::-1])

# reverse the left list back and join it to the right list
subl = left[::-1] + right

print(subl)
['3=', 'fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd', ';']
```

Comment: How to get the list including `=` and `;` ?? like this `['3=', 'fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd', ';']` instead of `['fd', 'dfdf', 'keyword', 'ssd', 'sdsd']`

Comment: @qwww Than you need to implement your own `takewhile()` function. See my edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below function :

```
extract = ['1','2','3=','fd','dfdf','keyword','ssd','sdsd',';','dds']

def get_output_list(extract, key): 
    equals_indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(extract) if '=' in j]
    semicolon_indices = [i for i,j in enumerate(extract) if ';' in j]
    if key not in extract or len(equals_indices) == 0 or len(semicolon_indices) == 0: 
        return 'no match found1'
    keyword_index = extract.index(key) 
    if any([keyword_index<i for i in semicolon_indices]) and any([keyword_index>i for i in equals_indices]) : 
        required_equal_index = keyword_index - equals_indices[0]
        required_semicolon_index = semicolon_indices[0] - keyword_index
        for i in equals_indices: 
            if (i < keyword_index) and required_equal_index > i: 
                required_equal_index = i
        for i in semicolon_indices: 
            if (i > keyword_index) and (required_semicolon_index < i) :
                required_semicolon_index = i
        return extract[required_equal_index:required_semicolon_index+1]
    else : 
        return 'no match found'
```